# C++ Development CodeBlock Ubuntu with Boost Library

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, codeblocks

I majorly work in Java but I have to switch to C++ for development for one project.
I done my research and find that in order to do portable code in C++, I need to use Boost or QT libraries etc. Therefore, now I download CodeBlock IDE in Ubuntu but afraid how to start building project. I search alot in the web to how to use Boost with CodeBlock but each time I only find it working/configure with Windows. http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef

Can please guide me regarding how to configure Boost library with CodeBlock in Ubuntu so that I can write Portable code.
Please also let me know if I am wrong in direction to write portable code which must be support in both Linux and Windows environment.

Comment: Boost has plenty of documents on it's own site to help set it up... (All flavours of OS)

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

Comment: You can use Eclipse CDT or Qt Creator, which are much more feature-rich and have nice documentation.

Comment: Check this link it worked for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663336/how-to-add-boost-library-to-codeblocks-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

If you dont't need the latest version of boost you should install boost on ubuntu using

```
apt-get install libboost*
```