# How to add boost library to Code::Blocks in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boost, codeblocks

How to add the boost library to a Code::Blocks project in Linux Ubuntu? For example I want to add `regex` lib.

I've already installed the boost library with:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Full example `how to` will be most valuable.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `-lboost_regex` to the link options and you should be fine. Other often used dependencies: `-lboost_system -lboost_serialization -lboost_thread -lpthread -lboost_filesystem`

Answer (score 2):

Two steps to finish:

1. Include the header files. If you set everything as default, the headers will be installed at

> /usr/include/boost

. 
 2. Select the links you're going to use during compiling. It's default location is

> /usr/lib

**ATTENTION:**
It seems to me that the

> -lboost_system

is always needed. So be careful if you need -lboost_filesystem or some libs else.